# What is the problem of writing data type of member variable in constructor?

Tags: java, types, constructor, nullpointerexception

```
public class Set {
    int[] elements;
    public Set() {
        int[] elements= new int[0];
    }
}
```

The code above cause NullPointerException.

In contrast the code bellow don't cause NullpointerExceoption and works well.

```
public class Set {
    int[] elements;
    public Set() {
       elements= new int[0];
    }
}
```

The only difference between two codes are whether giving int[] which is type of member variable or not.

Why type cause exception?
My guess was that constructor would not do anything. But I found that it do something mysterious by constructor. Then what does the constructor actually do in first code and why it cause the exception?

Comment: In your first code snippet you are declaring and setting a variable that is local to the function.  In your 2nd snippet you are assigning a value to the member variable.  In neither case do I see anything that would cause a NullPointerException.

Comment: Although the fact that you have created an array of size 0, will be problematic if you try to access it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, `int[] elements = new int[0];` you define a local variable, elements, as an array of size 0.

In the second example, you assign an array of size 0 to the instance variable elements.